# How to generate a large number of instances effectively in Java

Tags: java

I have a class with 5 possible different attributes, each of those attributes have a specific range of values (64 different values to be precise) and I'm trying to generate each different possible outcome.
I estimated that in total I would have over 500k uniques instances of that class. My goal is to generate all unique outcome and store them in a database for later use. It would be nice if that "generator" can be easily upgradable or reused efficiently.

The reason why I created that post is that I want to know if there is a way for me to generate effectively and not doing each one of them with a slight difference one after another. I initially thought of trying multi-threading but I'm not used to it, so it may not even be close to what I'm looking for.

I'm using java 8 but I'm not bound to that version.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough in my explanation and please excuse me if I made some mistakes in writting this post. Thanks for reading and have a nice day.

Comment: Why do you need to create them in advance, and what's the use in storing them in a database? If you can programmatically create them, it's faster to generate them than read them from the database. What are you [actually trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Take a look at load testing and data generator tools. If you are are going to pre-generate and store them for later use, does it really matter how efficient or effective the approach is? You could run it for days as long as you know beforehand when you're going to start the 'real' app that requires them?

Comment: @Kayaman the idea is to later create a weighting algorithm based on the attributes and their value to pick which combination of attribute/value will be better for a given situation. Also, I would like to have a global vision of what's available, this part does not have a pratical use so to speak it's just a personal preference.

Comment: @KevinHooke Thanks I will take a look at that. It is in fact not that important that the generation code is efficient but I'd prefer not to have my computer run for hours, maybe even days, to simulate all the possibilities. Another factor is that the range of available values may increases and so is the number of possible attributes. Therefore I fear that when the time comes for me to rerun the generation algorithm with new values, it will have to generate already existing combination plus the new ones.

Comment: This is what the cloud is for :-)

Comment: "I would have over 500k uniques instances"  — No, I don't think so. Every possible combination of 5 factors, each with set of 64 values, produces a *billion* elements, billion with a "b", not a half million, by my calculation of (64 ^ 5) = 1,073,741,824.

Answer (score 1):

## Creating half million objects takes a half second

Creating a half million objects with five fields takes under a half second. See example code below. So it seems you have fallen into the trap of *premature optimization*, expecting a performance problem before actually proving one.

As [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424341/how-to-generate-a-large-number-of-instances-effectively-in-java/70431803#comment124501367_70424341), your math confuses me. You expect 500K instances by combining each of 64 values for each of five attributes. But a Cartesian product of 64 ^ 5 = 1,073,741,824 — over a billion rather than a half million.

So in my example below I used 3 attributes with 64 values each, and created those twice for a total of 524,288, close to your desired half million.

To mix things up, I varied the data type for the three attributes: A custom enum, `LocalDate` objects, and `Locale` objects.

To make things more challenging, the example dynamically generates a UUID and captures the current moment.

```java
package work.basil.many;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.*;

public class Many
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Many app = new Many();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        // Initialize.
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        enum Color
        {
            AliceBlue, AntiqueWhite, Aqua, Aquamarine, Azure, Beige, Bisque, Black, BlanchedAlmond, Blue, BlueViolet, Brown, BurlyWood, CadetBlue, Chocolate, Coral,
            CornflowerBlue, Cornsilk, Crimson, Cyan, DarkBlue, DarkCyan, DarkGoldenRod, DarkGray, DarkGreen, DarkKhaki, DarkMagenta, DarkOliveGreen, DarkOrange,
            DarkOrchid, DarkRed, DarkSalmon, DarkSeaGreen, DarkSlateBlue, DarkSlateGray, DarkTurquoise, DarkViolet, DeepPink, DeepSkyBlue, DimGray, DodgerBlue,
            FireBrick, FloralWhite, ForestGreen, Fuchsia, Gainsboro, GhostWhite, Gold, GoldenRod, Gray, Green, GreenYellow, HoneyDew, HotPink, IndianRed, Indigo,
            Ivory, Khaki, Lavender, LavenderBlush, LawnGreen, LemonChiffon, LightBlue, LightCoral
        }

        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );
        List < LocalDate > dates = startDate.datesUntil( startDate.plusDays( 64 ) ).toList();

        List < Locale > locales = Arrays.stream( Locale.getAvailableLocales() ).limit( 64 ).toList();

        record Blah( UUID id , Instant instant , Color color , LocalDate date , Locale locale )
        {
        }

        // Populate.
        List < Blah > blahs = new ArrayList <>( ( int ) Math.pow( 64 , 3 ) * 2 );
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
        {
            for ( Color color : Color.values() )
            {
                for ( LocalDate date : dates )
                {
                    for ( Locale locale : locales )
                    {
                        blahs.add( new Blah( UUID.randomUUID() , Instant.now() , color , date , locale ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Report.
        System.out.println( "blahs.size() = " + blahs.size() );
        System.out.println( "blahs.get(0) = " + blahs.get( 0 ) );  // First.
        System.out.println( "blahs.get(blahs.size()) = " + blahs.get( blahs.size() - 1 ) );  // Last.

        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start );
        System.out.println( "elapsed = " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

When running this code in Java 17 on a [MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Apple_Silicon_revision) chip, and 16 gigs of memory.

```
blahs.size() = 524288
blahs.get(0) = Blah[id=68f1478b-de38-4217-b28a-8f3b65c82e47, instant=2021-12-21T07:11:35.896362Z, color=AliceBlue, date=2022-01-01, locale=]
blahs.get(blahs.size()) = Blah[id=58b1e46f-e09a-42a2-819f-e35bae197a27, instant=2021-12-21T07:11:36.224003Z, color=LightCoral, date=2022-03-05, locale=pl_PL_#Latn]
elapsed = PT0.406977625S
```